# Using radio buttons to collect answers in C sharp, how can this be done?

Tags: c#, winforms

My current situation: I am writing a csharp quiz, in forms (Visual Studio).

It is a multiple choice quiz, with the question followed by 3 choices, as radio buttons.

My question: How do I get an answer from a radio button, and then how can I convert all of the answers to provide the user with a correct answers %?

I need to hard code the answers and questions into the program, and cannot use databases. I'm basically at the wall of my limited knowledge (noob).

Comment: It's not clear what radio buttons have to do with an array. But you should definitely create a `Question` class with the relevant data, rather than having all those separate methods... You should also put some effort into formatting code when you post on Stack Overflow - if your real code isn't indented, fix that... and if it *is*, make sure it's indented the same way when you post here. Beyond that, it's unclear exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Apologies for the formatting, we are just starting programming and so I'm a total noob., What I need is to use radio buttons to select from a multiple choice question. Then store that answer so I can later provide a % of correct answers.

Comment: _A gigabyte is bigger than a megabyte - Depends:_ I love this one ;)

Comment: Right, but it's not clear what that has to do with arrays... basically you seem to have a number of issues, and you've asked a vague question which ends up boiling down to "I don't like the way my code is at the moment, please fix it." Stack Overflow works best with *very specific* questions. What do you not understand about arrays? What do you not understand about radio buttons? Write a question about *each* of them, potentially. (As for the formatting - if you're coding in an IDE, you should be able to ask the IDE to format it for you.)

Comment: Question 1 - How do I store an answer from a radio button? Question 2 - How would I then use those stored answers to provide a percentage of correct answers. You're right, I don't like my code at the moment, but I want  to learn a "correct" way to achieve what I want, if I wanted an easy way I could have paid someone. I just want to learn it.

Comment: So instead of putting that in a comment, edit your question - remove the 250+ lines of code which are mostly irrelevant to that matter, explain what you've tried, and exactly what the problem is. (Do you not know how to get the answer *from* a radio button, or what to do with it afterwards?) Basically, please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints - all the way through - and then write decent questions.

Comment: I hope this improves clarity, and highlights my issue a little better. Thanks Jon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a form called QuestionForm and either make properties that set text of your labels or make the labels public. Create a function on that form called ShowQuestion that will show the form as a dialog and return the selected answer as an integer. The rest is based on your question before you edited it

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private struct Question
    {
        public Question(string q, string a1, string a2,string a3,int correct)
        {
            Q = q;
            A1 = a1;
            A2 = a2;
            A3 = a3;
            CorrectChoice = correct;
        }
        public string Q;
        public string A1;
        public string A2;
        public string A3;
        public int CorrectChoice;
    }

    Question[] questions;
    int correctChoise = -1;
    bool[] correctAnswers = new bool[10];

    public Form1()
    {
    InitializeComponent();
    questions = new Question[] 
        { new Question("Linux is:", "An operating system", "A kernel", "A device", 0),
          new Question("cisco are a global brand, who specialise in::", "Networking", "Gamingl" ,"Mobile applications", 0)
         // Add more questions here
        };
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void startbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i=0;i<10 ;i++ )
        {
            int answer = QuestionForm.ShowQuestion( questions[i].Q,
                questions[i].A1,
                questions[i].A2,
                questions[i].A3);

            correctAnswers[i] = answer == questions[i].CorrectChoise;
        }

        int correct = correctAnswers.Where(x=>x).Count();
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Test Finished with {0}% correct", 100 * ((double)correct/10.0)));
    }

}
```

Question Form:

```
public class QuestionForm
{
  // skipped constructor and controls
  public static int ShowQuestion(string q, string a1, string a2,string a3,int correct)
  {
    QuestionForm f = new QuestionForm();
    f.qtnlabel.Text = q;
    f.radbtnans1.Text = a1;
    f.radbtnans2.Text = a2;
    f.radbtnans3.Text = a3;
    f.ShowDialog(owner);
    if (f.radbtnans1.Checked)
      return 0;
    else if (f.radbtnans2.Checked)
      return 1;
    else if (f.radbtnans3.Checked)
      return 2;
  }
}
```

Comment: I can make them public that's no issue, but "Create a function on that form called ShowQuestion that will show the form as a dialog and return the selected answer as an integer"  I'm not 100% what you mean by this, could you do one as an example? Thanks again for the help..

Comment: Hero! Regarding the original post, would I just replace my code with yours or should I just keep the radi button text?

Comment: Replace you startbtn_click 
Get rid of all the Question1() Question2()...etc  functions
add anew form called QuestionForm move the radio buttons and labels there. Thats going to be your dialog box

Comment: It isn't at the moment, but you've given me more than enough to work with! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Only attempting to solve the problem you've asked, the code here shows how to get the value from a checkbox and get sums and averages based on it:

```
        List<int> values = new List<int>();

        if (radioButton1.Checked) //correct answer to question 1 is box 1
            values.Add(1);
        else
            values.Add(0);

        if(radioButton4.Checked) //correct answer to question 2 is box 4
            values.Add(1);
        else
            values.Add(0);

        int sum = values.Sum();
        int count = values.Count();

        double score = sum / count * 100; //percentage score
```

Again, just to very simply answer your questions about Radio Buttons in WinForms and getting quiz scores.

Comment: Thanks Matt, so would I enter this in the code for each button click event?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't do this anywhere.  But, if you have a CalculateScore method, you can use a function like this to get the score of the test.  Again, this is mostly to demonstrate how to find out if a radio button is checked and how to calculate averages based off of it.  Note: You almost never need to handle the click event on RadioButtons.  If you put them in a container like a GroupBox, they will handle the selection themselves